# Reading custom annotation for JUNIT

Tags: java, junit, reflection, annotations

I have a custom annotation which I use as config to start off one time set-up for Junit.

```
@Target(TYPE) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation{
   String host();
   int port();
}
```

Test class:

```
@MyAnnotation(host="0.0.0.0", port=4567)
public class MyTest extends MyAbstractClass{
   @Test
   public void myTest(){
      //do testy things
   }   
}
```

Superclass:

```
public class MyAbstractClass{

   @BeforeAll
   public static void start(){
    Config cfg = readConfig();
    //Use config to do one time set-up
   }

   private static Config readConfig(){
      MyAnnotation ann = MyTest.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
      return new Config(ann.host(), ann.port());
   }
}
```

So currently, I hardcode the name of the test class (**MyTest**) in **readConfig(..)**.
This won't work when I add a second test class.

One way to solve it is:

- Add another @BeforeAll method in MyTest which will call the @BeforeAll in super-class and pass the class name as a param.

However, I am curious if I can read the name of the **executing** subclass in the superclass via some reflexion magic.
Any ideas are most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Use `getClass()` in the constructor?

Comment: could polymorphism be a possible answer? what if you define start() in your subclass MyTest and pass class name from there? Although that way you might have to define it in every Test class you write.

Comment: Ganesh,  what you are suggesting will work (although can't use polymorphism as @BeforeAll can only be used in static methods). However, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this for every test (which could be hundreds)

Comment: @johannes Kuhn Can't use this reference when calling super(..) but can do this MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass(). But still would like to do it via reflexion though.

Comment: I mean in the constructor of `MyAbstractClass`: `public MyAbstractClass() {Class<?> clazz = getClass(); ...}`.

Comment: I need to get the name of the subclass (MyTest) in the superclass (MyAbstractClass). If I do what you mention, I will get MyAbstractClass in MyAbstractClass.

Comment: Nope, you will get `MyTest`. [Example](https://ideone.com/ZbSrUm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the `@BeforeAll` annotation suggests you are using JUnit 5. In this case, you can use.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;

public class MyAbstractClass {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void start(TestInfo ti) {
        Config cfg=readConfig(ti.getTestClass().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new));
        //Use config to do one time set-up
    }

    private static Config readConfig(Class<?> testClass) {
         MyAnnotation ann = testClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
         return new Config(ann.host(), ann.port());
    }
}
```

See also the [`TestInfo` API documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html).

This is not “Reflection Magic” but a feature provided by JUnit itself, but it’s also only JUnit which knows that the invocation of a `static` method annotated with `@BeforeAll` is associated with a particular test class it is going to process.