# Get a test method metadata within parent test class in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Given the following test classes:

- In the `ContractTestRunner` described common configs for all test
  methods;
- The `MessageTests` class `extends ContractTestRunner` and    defines
  test methods;

I would like to get metadata of the runnable method (name of the method) inside `setUp()` to then implement specific logic specific for each method because in my case it's impossible to add this logic directly in each method.

Could somebody prompt me whether it is even possible to get it at this stage? Maybe It's somehow possible to retrieve it from `SpringTestContext`?

```java
        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @SpringBootTest
        public class ContractTestRunner {
        
             @MockBean
             MessageRepository messageRepository;
             
             @Before
             public void setUp() {
    
                 // Here I want to get metadata of a runnable method
                 .....
    
                  // some logic here
                  ......
                  given(messageRepository.findAll(....)).willReturn(...) 
                  given(messageRepository.findAll(any(Pageable.classs))).willReturn(...)
                  ........
             }
    
        }

        public class MessageTests extends ContractTestRunner {
         
              whenPageable_isNotNull_shouldReturnList() { .... }
              whenPageable_isNull_shouldThrowException() { .... }

        }
```

P.S.  In my project `MessageTests` are not located in the source of the project but are generated at the stage of compilation automatically. I don't want to overhead my question with additional unrelated information not to confuse people. I am interested in whether it is possible to do exactly how I have described it just in parent class without touching the child class with methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading custom annotation for JUNIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726617/reading-custom-annotation-for-junit)

Comment: I think no, I mean I don't need to scan all method annotated by @Test manually. As I understand when test methods will be launched it should create a new object internally of class FraemworkMethod or smth like that. I need to get metadata of the method already runnable by JUnit context.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method in your parent class and override it when desired in your child class.

### `ContractTestRunner`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ContractTestRunner {
        
    @MockBean
    MessageRepository messageRepository;
             
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println(getTestMetadata()); // or whatever you want to do with it
                 .....
    
        }

        // New methods
        protected Map<String, String> getTestMetadata() {
            return Map.of();
        }

}
```

### `ContractTestRunner`:

```java
public class MessageTests extends ContractTestRunner {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getTestMetadata() {
        return Map.of("something", "special");
    }
       
}
```

If you want to force all child classes to override the method, you could also mark the parent class and the method as `abstract`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But In my project, it's impossible because MessageTests are not located in the source of the project but are generated at the stage of compilation automatically. I don't want to overhead my question with additional unrelated information not to confuse people. I am interested in whether it is possible to do exactly how I describe it just in parent class without touching child class with methods.